# Which flag should be raised for answers about Kali Linux?

Tags: discussion, flagging

I came across [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1080145/816190) for [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1016894/im-having-issues-connecting-to-ubuntu-14-04-from-chromebook/1080145#1080145).

> We tried Kali Linux on Crouton with Enlightment desktop, and got the same error. It turns out they changed dbus to use different options syntax, or something like that, and they're busy updating different desktops and distros to make them work. We discovered that [only xfce4 is supported on Kali at this time](https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton/wiki/Kali). It may be different on Ubuntu. They say to [try different desktops](https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton/issues/3898) like LXDE.
>
> The docs on Crouton could use some help.
>
> What worked for us finally, today:
>
> Install the <strike>kiwi extension</strike>... Rats, I mean use crouton from the crosh shell to update the chroot with the -t xiwi,xfce4,extension options in that order. Presently, the options *must* be listed xiwi first, or it [won't work](https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton/issues/1279).
>
> `sudo sh ~/Downloads/crouton -t xiwi,xfce,extension -u -n kali-rolling`
>
> The -n (name) is optional, in case you have more than one chroot. You can do this in the Chrome OS Developer (crosh) shell. Here's another weird thing we ran into. If the newly-installed Chrome OS Developer shell from the Google App Store pops up with a blank screen and refuses to work, it is probably already installed. Uninstall that one and access crosh with CTRL-Alt-t hotkey. Gee, it would be nice if this was more intuitive.
>
> Next, get the [crouton integration extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/crouton-integration/gcpneefbbnfalgjniomfjknbcgkbijom/related?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog) for the Chrome browser. The link to it does not, at this time, appear on the crouton install hints screen, and oddly did not come up in the web store, app store, or google searches. But it does appear on the [Crouton GitHub Page under Prerequisites](https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton#prerequisites).
>
> Finally, once everything is in order, try starting the desktop with the xiwi target.
>       `sudo startxfce4 -t xiwi`

**That was the answer while this question/post was asked/posted.**

So my question is "Is it right to refer Kali in answers? If not, which flag should be raised?" Since I am totally confused about which flag to be raised.

Comment: It's OT, but it doesn't pass the threshold for flagging for me.  I just look at it and shrug.  Think about how obnoxious it would be if you were a guy that used one tool and someone else used a different one tool.  Answering about the tool you use might be a little irritating, but it's nowhere near as rude as trying to shout the answer class down.  That said, if the question was something that applied only to Kali, it would be both off-topic and no-repro.

Comment: See [What should I do with answers about other Linux distros](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/16472/what-should-i-do-with-answers-about-other-linux-distros). My experience is, flagging such posts will often lead to a declined flag. My belief is, if an answer won't work on Ubuntu it should probably be deleted as NAA, but that's very hard to know. What tends to happen is that nothing is done. Such answers sometimes gather upvotes (and anonymous upvotes) over time. What I'm saying is, two years of moderation later, I still don't know the answer to my own question :S

Comment: @RobotHumans If I consider the comment by Mark Kirby on [this answer](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/16474/816190), at least downvoting doesn't make me rude. I guess.

Comment: @Zanna Yeah. I was totally confused since no flag was appropriate for the same. Once for a while I thought I should raise ** in need of moderator intervention** flag but found it not right. Don't you think that there should be a flag like, **Off-topic answer** or **Answer that may work on different distro but not necessarily on Ubuntu** something like that?

Comment: @Kulfy the thing is, we don't know whether such answers should be deleted... if you think something should be deleted and there isn't a standard flag for it, you should flag for moderator attention, then mods can take a look and decide what to do (I don't agree with Fabby that mods are "understaffed" and overworked - they are able to call an election any time they need more hands on deck. Being a mod is a desirable role, and handling tricky situations is exactly what mods are supposed to do.) But, I don't know whether that applies to the case in point...

Comment: ... because I don't know whether deletion is what should happen to that post. Note that mods can also convert answers into comments on questions and other answers, something other users cannot do, and sometimes that may be the right thing for an answer that says "on Mint, you need to do x and y to get this to work". But the answer you show is much too long to be a comment. If there's no action that would always be appropriate to the situation, then there's no reason to have a flag for it. All I can suggest is that if you are in doubt about whether something should be handled in a way you...

Comment: ... are unable to do yourself, you can certainly flag it for mod attention (at the risk of a declined flag, because the flagging system is rather a blunt instrument) or bring it to chat, or bring it to meta. Downvoting may be appropriate, as for answers which are wrong or unreliable or (perhaps) fail to state important limitations of the procedure they suggest. But what you have raised is an unresolved issue imho and it's something I am troubled by every time I encounter it.

Comment: @Zanna Such a long comment ;). I think to some extent you have answered my question simply in comments. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe I should write an answer! I thought perhaps this question is a duplicate of mine.  But although I accepted the answer, I consider it unresolved!

Answer (score 9):

The OP wrote in the first sentence of his answer:

> We tried Kali & Ubuntu Linux on Crouton with Enlightment desktop and got the same error.

The OP also posted the following comment below his answer:

> The process is effectively the same for Ubuntu. Kali is just the first one we tried.

I would give this answer the benefit of the doubt and not flag it. If this was a question instead of an answer and it was tagged with either [kali-linux-tools](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/kali-linux-tools) or [katoolin](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/katoolin) then the Tag Info of these two tags would provide additional information to reviewers simply by hovering the mouse over the tag.

Comment: When i asked this question OP hasn't mentioned Ubuntu. Now, his answer and comment both has talked about Ubuntu. Also, that was just a sample answer. Many a times I have came across answers which do not have anything to do with Ubuntu, like how they solved in CentOS. I just wanted to know which flag should be raised. Thanks :)

Comment: Raise whatever flag best applies or no flag if no flag applies, and when in doubt comment below the post to give the OP a chance to edit his post. If you make a mistake, you can retract your flag by going back to the same post, clicking the `flag` link below the post again, and clicking the **Retract Flag** button in the lower right corner of the flag popup window.

Answer (score 3):

Well, I was going to post it as a comment but hadn't earned enough rep. points for that yet.

I can remove the Kali reference and say "other distros" because it's a general dBus problem affecting multiple desktops at the moment.

Linux distros run so well on the Chromebook, once we got them set up, that we decided to wipe out the BIOS and install Native.

Comment: That's good :-)

Comment: Only caveat, Chromebook Apps (Chrome packaged apps and most hosted apps) used to be available and would load on Linux. That is no longer the case as Chromebook is going their own way.

 https://developer.chrome.com/native-client/migration

The preferred developer path seems to be "progressive web apps" that work with multiple browsers and community standards.

https://blog.chromium.org/2016/08/from-chrome-apps-to-web.html

https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps/